# Turn LED on after a particular time for a particular time period

Tags: gpio, led, home-automation

I am doing a small project which consists of turning LEDs on and off using the GPIO library. I am able to successfully turn the LED's on and off using a browser on my laptop. But now I want the LEDs to turn on automatically at a specified time for a short duration.

Example: If I set the LED's to turn on after 12:00 for 2 hours, then the Raspberry Pi would automatically turn them on at 12:00 for 2 hours.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: Yes, that is perfectly possible.  What have you tried and why didn't it work?

Comment: I havent tried it actually.But I googled for it but didnt find any suitable links.

Comment: So, after thinking about it, I think you can do this from X and from the command line, are you accessing your pi through ssh? Do you need to be root to turn the leds on or off?

Answer (score 5):

Let's break this answer in two parts: scheduling a task and turning a led on and off, than wrap together. You can go to the end and just get the script if you prefer!

## Scheduling a task

So I would suggest you use the `atd` for one time scheduling in Raspbian. If you need something repetitive, use `cron` - I will cover here only how to use the `at` command. More details here: https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.task-scheduling-cron-atd.html

First, you need to install it!

```
sudo apt-get install at
```

Now for using it, see the date right now on your raspbian - I'm assuming you are connected to it using ssh or is accessing through the terminal.

```
date
```

Let's make a blank folder on your home for testing purpose

```
mkdir ~/test
cd ~/test
```

Let's **schedule** a job!!

```
echo "echo \"teste\" > ~/test/test.log " | at 10:52
```

Let's wait it to be executed!!!

```
watch ls
```

The watch command will execute the command after it repeatedly and will output it's output with a clock, so we can confirm it works! (an archive named `test.log` be created at the scheduled time.

## Turning a LED on and off

Now you need to make a script to turn on and off a LED - I don't know how you are doing this and schedule it with using the at command. We will use the `gpio` utility from `wiringpi`. Let's learn about it.

```
sudo apt-get install wiringpi
```

I will suppose you want to turn on and off led 5, but do whatever you want. Let's test if it works. Try:

```
gpio -g mode 5 out
gpio -g write 5 1
```

You can turn the led off using:

```
gpio -g write 5 0
```

## Let's do both!

Ok, now we need to wrap all of this in a bash script for ease of use.

Let's create ledsched.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

timeat="$1"
duration="$2"
ledpin="$3"

endtime=`date +%H:%M -d " $timeat today + $duration"`

gpio -g mode $ledpin out
echo "gpio -g write $ledpin 1" | at $timeat
echo "gpio -g write $ledpin 0" | at $endtime
```

And call it using (remember to use first `chmod +x ledsched.sh` ):

```
./ledsched.sh 12:00 2hours 5
```

I'm scheduling to turn pin 5 on at 12:00 and off after 2 hours. If your led is at pin 5 it should work!

---

Oh, if you do have access to the visual interface, you can use the alarm-clock-applet. Install it from the command line with `sudo apt-get install alarm-clock-applet` .

Answer (score 1):

## Making the script

To start, you need to make sure that your Raspberry Pi is connected to the internet. This is needed to track time. Then type in this code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import datetime
import time

pin = your_output_pin_here
GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.OUT)

while True:
    time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")
    if time == "12:00":
        GPIO.output(pin, True)
        time.sleep(number_of_seconds_for_led_to_be_on_here)
        GPIO.output(pin, False)
    time.sleep(0.030)
```

Replace things like 12:00 and your_output_pin_here with your own values. Every 30 milliseconds, it checks whether it is 12:00. If it is, it turns on the LED. It then waits a number of seconds, then turns it back off.

## Editing the Crontab

If you want this program to be run whenever you start the Raspberry Pi, go into LXTerminal and type this:

> sudo crontab -e

It will open a text document. Use the arrow keys to navigate to the bottom, then type this:

> @reboot sudo python /path/to/your/python/file.py &

Replace "/path/to/your/python/file.py" with the path to your python file (like /home/pi/timed_led.py). Do CTRL+O and RETURN to save. Then to exit, do CTRL-X.

When you start up your Pi, it will take a while to boot up, then it will run the program. If you ever want to stop it doing this, then do sudo crontab -e again and put a hash (SHIFT+3) at the front of the line.

**I really hope this helps!**

Comment: This was a really good question, I have been puzzled by getting python time for years: I only learnt how the day before yesterday! But recently, I have found huge uses for it in all circumstances. And just remember, StackExchange is here to help; I'm always happy to give my skills to others!

Comment: Thanks a ton !!! :). This solved both of my time related and scheduling problem. Btw is there any way through which i can obtain the time from raspberry pi's without any internet connection ?